# VB.NET - This piece of code will run in VS2010 but not in VS2008 - why?

Tags: database, vb.net, visual-studio

I coded this thing up in VS2010, it worked fine. I needed to port it to VS2008, which went smoothly, aside from fixing how a few lines were worded. But it won't run, and my error codes say it's in opening this database.

```
com = New OleDbConnection(DB_Path)
com.Open()
```

With a string at the top defining DB_Path

```
Public Const DB_Path As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0;Data Source=.\ASPNetDB.mdb"
```

Those two lines of code at the only thing in a Try statement, so they're the only thing that could be going wrong here. And yes, I made sure to copy the database into the new directory. I even tried using the full direct path in there and that didn't work either.

So what have I missed?

Comment: Of course I would be stupid enough to not check what the actual exception thrown is. "Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0" provider is not registered on this local machine. Can VS2008 not use that?

Comment: Are all the service packs up to date on VS2008? Are you running a 64bit machine?

Comment: @JohnDR I'm running a 64bit machine. And I think VS2008 is up to date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On a 64bit machine in VS2008 you need to set the target CPU to 32bit in the project properties, no 64 bit DLL exist for database access. I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess-- but you may have to use a different Jet provider (not 4.0) in VS 2008, since it will be targeting an earlier release of .Net.

Comment: You're right, I just checked the exception message and it said that. I can't believe I didn't think to check that. Do you know what version VS2008 would use? 2.0?